# SMTP setup on wordpresswith mi clients email

Tags: wordpress, azure, smtp, wp-mail

I'm developing a wordpress site for my client. He asked to use SMTP for sending emails. I admit it's my first time setting up SMTP on a wordpress site.
I'm using the WP Mail SMTP pro plugin in order to do that.
He's managing his account on outlook so that is why I use the pro version.

I understand I need to setup an azure account with his credentials but of course I will not ask him for his password nor do I want to make him do this alone cause he isn't very technological.

Is there a way to setup the SMTP without using his password?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can have an authorised SMTP relay in Outlook based on IP address but that, in my experience, depends on a savvy Outlook IT support.

An alternative is set up an email account just for that purpose so the password is not sensitive. This obviously costs as O365 is charged 'per seat'.

I have also, when all else fails, set up a subdomain that has email and is controllable within the web hosting

You shouldn't need the pro version, just the usual SMTP credentials.

Comment: I used no authentication (no password, only user name) and found the outlook setting on the internet but it doesnt work: CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO wp.010.co.il
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.

Comment: You will need the Outlook manager to allow SMTP relaying from the IP address of your web server